# Oracle: System table/view/proc which tracks proc/function/pkg invocation?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a system table/view/procedure/whatever which can be used to determine the last time a proc, function, or packaged procedure was invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

You can check in v$locked_object to see if it is currently being used.
If you have auditing enabled for that object you may see something in the file/table.
If it is INVALID in ALL_OBJECTS then you could look at what dependencies it has, see their last_ddl_time and get an idea when it might have been invalidated.